# wget connection timed out on same server

Tags: linux, networking, server, wget, centos7

I've got a very strange problem.

There's a cron job on the server to run a script daily:

```
wget -O /dev/null --timeout=300 --tries=1 "http://website.com/script"
```

It was all working well since about two weeks ago, I started receiving errors:

```
--2016-07-13 09:45:01--  http://website.com/script
Resolving website.com (website.com)... 11.22.33.44
Connecting to website.com (website.com)|11.22.33.44|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Giving up.
```

These are some information for this question:

1. The cron job is on the same server of http://website.com hosted.
2. I can access the script (http://website.com/script) correctly from browser on my desktop.
3. The server is CentOS 7, with WHM and cPanel installed.

Anyone know what could be the issue? or how do I suppose to identify the issue?

Thanks

Comment: this means the site went down, that's why it's giving up. ping the website and make sure the url is still available.

Comment: No, the website is up, and I can access it from browser on my desktop.

Comment: Since `website.com` resolves to `11.22.33.44` and not `127.0.0.1` (or similar), all sorts of network-related issues may arise. Is `11.22.33.44` address actually assigned to one of the server's network interfaces? (use `ifconfig` as root to find out)

Comment: That IP has been used as an shared IP addresses, same as the cPanel and WHM IP address for the server. How do I check? It looks like the DNS is fine, it resolves the correct IP address from the domain name, but then connection to port 80 is time out.

Comment: Do you have a proxy set up? If that's the case, you might have to tell wget about it.

Answer (score 2):

If the issue still is unresolved..
You could try running wget in debug mode to see if you get some more info.

```
wget -dv -O /dev/null --timeout=300 --tries=1 "http://website.com/script"
```

Also, confirm if the resolved IP "11.22.33.44" belongs to one of the servers NIC's.

`ip a s` (ip address show)  or

`ifconfig -a`

If the IP is not listed, It could be that the ip "11.22.33.44" is a public facing address of the company's firewall. And that the FW is directing requests on port 80 from the outside/internet (where you're browser is) to that specific server. And the Firewall/Nat/Proxy, could be configured to not allow requests coming from inside the network, reaching the external IP of the firewall and getting back in.

If this is the case, you could try changing you're wget using the internal ip address, something like: (still using `-dv` for debugging, remove after)

```
wget -dv -O /dev/null --timeout=300 --tries=1 --header="Host: website.com" http://127.0.0.1/script
```

Note1: the `--header="Host: website.com"` will tell you're webserver what site you wanna reach

Note2: maybe you'll have to change the IP: 127.0.0.1 (localhost address) to one of the server's NIC addresses.

Answer (score 0):

If the website is up try a different command.

`*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/wget` -q -O temp.txt http://website.com/script

Comment: I tried, didn't get any outputs, and I don't think that one worked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Please write a comment instead.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding -H

```
wget -H -O /dev/null --timeout=300 --tries=1 "http://website.com/script"
```

Comment: Please phrase more assertively than "Try ...". Also, I doubt that this helps or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please explain how this works and why it solves the problem.