# wget cannot download the file although I can download it by browser

Tags: linux, http, download, connection, wget

Don't know what the wrong , but I've tried a lot of techniques but nothing seems to work .

My command was :

```
wget --referer="http://www.website.com" --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6" --header="Accept:text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5" --header="Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5" --header="Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate"--header="Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7" --header="Keep-Alive: 300" -dnv http://www.website.com/file.zip
```

But it didn't work ..

I tried to force it with IPV4 :

```
wget -4 http://website.com/file.zip
```

But in all cases , it hangs with this :

```
--2017-04-01 15:47:36--  http://website.com/file.zip
Resolving website.com... $#$#@#%#@%
Connecting to website.com|$#$#@#%#@%|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2017-04-01 15:47:39--  (try: 2)  http://website.com/file.zip
Resolving website.com... $#$#@#%#@%
Connecting to website.com|$#$#@#%#@%|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2017-04-01 15:47:42--  (try: 3)  http://website.com/file.zip
Resolving website.com... $#$#@#%#@%
Connecting to website.com|$#$#@#%#@%|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2017-04-01 15:47:46--  (try: 4)  http://website.com/file.zip
Resolving website.com... $#$#@#%#@%
Connecting to website.com|$#$#@#%#@%|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.
```

However , when I tried to download it through Firefox , it's been downloaded successfully !!

So is there anyway to download this file through wget ?
Or can I simulate the process of download of Firefox?

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428635/wget-connection-timed-out-on-same-server
Isn't it your case too?

Comment: @TGar , NO , thanks for your words!

Comment: Do you have a proxy set up? If that's the case, you might have to tell wget about it.

Comment: Could be some redirect happening. I've found using "curl" vs wget can help in situations like this. (apt install curl)

Comment: @Edmundo , There's no proxy .

Comment: @CareFree , No redirect , because as you saw above "failed: Connection timed out"

Comment: please post the output of "curl -vv http://yourwebsite.com/file.zip"

Comment: Can you attach the real file URL if it is convenient?

Comment: @CareFree , it hangs with :
* About to connect() to domain port 80 (#0)
*   Trying xx.xx.xxx.xxx...

Comment: @shaochuancs , sorry , I can't .

Comment: Is there anyway to create a file that works as a go-between ?
Server -> AnotherServer(contains the go-between file) -> My PC

Comment: This is most certainly a network issue. wget and curl are attempting to open a TCP connection to the remote host and it's failing. It's obvious that the Firefox browser is using a different route to connect. I'd look into the network routing. It could also be the remote host is not returning traffic for whatever reason, security? Maybe it's looking for a HTTP header.